# Rotation and translation of a conic-section

Tags: matrices, conic-sections, rotations

I tried to solve the following exercises, so I want to ask you if my answers are correct.

> 1) Given the coordinates system $(O'; X'' Y'')$ asociated to the 
>   basis $B=[{b_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}; \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}; 
> > b_2=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}; \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}]$ with origin in 
>   $O'=(2;5)$ and the system $(O;XY)$ asociated to the standar basis, find the intersection between $Q: y''^2=-4 \sqrt{2} x''$ 
>   and the straight line in $(O,XY)$ $V=(0;5)+t(-1;1) t\epsilon R$

Well, first I tried to write $Q$ in terms of $X$ and $Y$, and not in terms of $X''$ and $Y''$. I used the formula: 
$(\begin{matrix} 
X''\\ 
Y'' \\ 
\end{matrix})$ =$(C)_B$ × $(\begin{matrix} 
X-2\\ 
Y-5 \\ 
\end{matrix})$

Then I replaced those values in the equation of $Q$ and I got $Q: \frac{(-x+y-3)^2}{2}=-4 \sqrt{2} \frac{(x+y-7)}{\sqrt{2}}$

After that, I found the intersection between $Q$ and $V$ using equations and I got that the intersection points in $(O;XY)$ are $P_1(3;2)$ and $P_2(-1;6)$

> 2)Given the coordinates system $(O,X'Y')$ asociated to the basis 
>   $B=[{b_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}; \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}; 
> > b_2=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}; \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}]$ with origin in 
>   $O=(0;0)$ and the ellipse $9X'^2+5Y'^2-3X'+2Y'-10=0$ find the 
>   coordinates of the centre of the ellipse in $(O,XY)$

So, here I found the centre of the ellipse in $(O,X'Y')$ and it was $(\frac{1}{6}; - \frac{1}{5})$, then, doing something similar to what I've done before I found out that the centre in $(O,XY)$ was $( \frac{11}{30 \sqrt{2}};$ $\frac{-1}{30 \sqrt{2}}$)

Comment: Are those vectors in the parameterization of the line $V$ expressed relative to the standard basis or $B$?

Comment: They are expressed in (O,XY)

Comment: You asked this same question verbatim yesterday (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3254868/265466). It’s considered very bad form here to delete and repost a question half a day later, especially if you did so just because the original instance hasn’t gotten any attention. Either edit the original question to add more information that might attract some attention to it or have some patience.

Comment: As I told you yesterday, you’ve got to stop deleting and reposting the exact same question every day. It’s considered _extremely_ bad form here. Doing so is not going to help attract answers to it.